# Calcium bioavailability in traditional tofu?

Tags: veganism, nutrition, food, dairy-substitutes, vegetarian-diet

As a vegan, I intend to use tofu as my main source of protein, iron and calcium. Therefore, I am concerned about bioavailability (i.e. absorption divided by intake) of iron and calcium in tofu.

As far as I know, there're two kinds of tofu, divided by a difference in their production process:

- Those treated with CaSO4, known in US/UK as "calcium-set tofu", and in China as "southern tofu".
- Those treated with MgCl2 (among other substances), known in US/UK as "traditional tofu" (not sure), and in China as "northern tofu".

These two kinds vary greatly in calcium content: roughly 300+mg/100g for the former, and 100+mg/100g for the latter. [[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jf052051r)]

There had been studies on the iron bioavailability in tofu ([[2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/21652792_Soy_protein_phytate_and_iron_absorption_in_humans)]).

There had also been studies on the calcium bioavailabity in **calcium-set** tofu ([[3](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1365-2621.2002.tb08873.x)],[[4](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1988.tb10210.x)]), which give us some good news (that calcium-set tofu is not even defeated by milk).

However, I hadn't found any infomation on the calcium bioavailabity in **traditional** tofu. So, could you share your relevant experiences, or point out some relevant studies?

---

**UPD**: Luckily I've found ways to get around this problem, so answer to this question doesn't matter much to me now.

I'll post links to another paper that I found quite useful, in case it can help somebody: [[5](https://xueshu.baidu.com/usercenter/paper/show?paperid=cf62b31b39493552a429b35f555816b7)], [[6](http://www.cnki.com.cn/article/cjfdtotal-guan802.019.htm)]

The paper is about mineral content in all kinds of common soy products in China, and it's written in Chinese.

Comment: Excellent question with science-based links!  Thank you!

Comment: Could you summarize what you decided to get around that problem?

Comment: @T.C.Proctor nothing interesting ... It's just that I found a store that sells certain soy products that are based on CaSO4 tofu.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that paper also say tofu products have from 300-3000 ppb lead? And at most 0.6mg per gram of Calcium, which seems very far off from the claim of 300mg/100g by a factor of five.